# Content always overlap fixed header and footer when using CSS print

Tags: html, css

I want to print web pages with Fixed header and footer appear on every page without overlapping. Here is my `HTML` codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

    <header>
      <h1>This header will go to every page.</h1>
    </header>  

    <div id="print_content">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color:#FF0000;">
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Steven</td>
            <td>25</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Steven</td>
            <td>25</td>
          </tr>
          ...
          ...  
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h1>This is footer will go to every page.</h1>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

And here is the `css` codes

```
<style>
footer, header {
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;

}

@media print {

  #print_content {
    margin-top:100px;
  }

  header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
  }

  footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
}
</style>
```

On the first page, the header displays **correct result**,
[image]

But the footer and content of the first page are **overlapping**

[image]

After the second page, now header will overlap the content. `margin-top` in **`@media print`** is not working anymore.[image]

I really need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    /* Styles go here */
    
    .page-header,
    .page-header-space {
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    .page-footer,
    .page-footer-space {
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    .page-footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      /* for demo */
      background: yellow;
      /* for demo */
    }
    
    .page-header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0mm;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      /* for demo */
      background: yellow;
      /* for demo */
    }
    
    .page {
      page-break-after: always;
    }
    
    @page {
      margin: 20mm
    }
    
    @media print {
      thead {
        display: table-header-group;
      }
      tfoot {
        display: table-footer-group;
      }
      button {
        display: none;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-header" style="text-align: center">
    I'm The Header
    <br/>
    <button type="button" onClick="window.print()" style="background: pink">
            PRINT ME!
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="page-footer">
    I'm The Footer
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position header-->
          <div class="page-header-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--*** CONTENT GOES HERE ***-->
          <div class="page">PAGE 1</div>
          <div class="page">PAGE 2</div>
          <div class="page" style="line-height: 3;">
            PAGE 3 - Long Content
            <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt metus eu consectetur rutrum. Praesent tempor facilisis dapibus. Aliquam cursus diam ac vehicula pulvinar. Integer lacinia non odio et condimentum. Aenean faucibus
            cursus mi, sed interdum turpis sagittis a. Quisque quis pellentesque mi. Ut erat eros, posuere sed scelerisque ut, pharetra vitae tellus. Suspendisse ligula sapien, laoreet ac hendrerit sit amet, viverra vel mi. Pellentesque faucibus nisl
            et dolor pharetra, vel mattis massa venenatis. Integer congue condimentum nisi, sed tincidunt velit tincidunt non. Nulla sagittis sed lorem pretium aliquam. Praesent consectetur volutpat nibh, quis pulvinar est volutpat id. Cras maximus odio
            posuere suscipit venenatis. Donec rhoncus scelerisque metus, in tempus erat rhoncus sed. Morbi massa sapien, porttitor id urna vel, volutpat blandit velit. Cras sit amet sem eros. Quisque commodo facilisis tristique. Proin pellentesque sodales
            rutrum. Vestibulum purus neque, congue vel dapibus in, venenatis ut felis. Donec et ligula enim. Sed sapien sapien, tincidunt vitae lectus quis, ultricies rhoncus mi. Nunc dapibus nulla tempus nunc interdum, sed facilisis ex pellentesque.
            Nunc vel lorem leo. Cras pharetra sodales metus. Cras lacus ex, consequat at consequat vel, laoreet ac dui. Curabitur aliquam, sapien quis congue feugiat, nisi nisl feugiat diam, sed vehicula velit nulla ac nisl. Aliquam quis nisi euismod
            massa blandit pharetra nec eget nunc. Etiam eros ante, auctor sit amet quam vel, fringilla faucibus leo. Morbi a pulvinar nulla. Praesent sed vulputate nisl. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
            mus. Aenean commodo mollis iaculis. Maecenas consectetur enim vitae mollis venenatis. Ut scelerisque pretium orci id laoreet. In sit amet pharetra diam. Vestibulum in molestie lorem. Nunc gravida, eros non consequat fermentum, ex orci vestibulum
            orci, non accumsan sem velit ac lectus. Vivamus malesuada lacus nec velit dignissim, ac fermentum nulla pretium. Aenean mi nisi, convallis sed tempor in, porttitor eu libero. Praesent et molestie ante. Duis suscipit vitae purus sit amet aliquam.
            Vestibulum lectus justo, lobortis a purus a, dapibus efficitur metus. Suspendisse potenti. Duis dictum ex lorem. Suspendisse nec ligula consectetur magna hendrerit ullamcorper et eget mauris. Etiam vestibulum sodales diam, eget venenatis nunc
            luctus quis. Ut fermentum placerat neque nec elementum. Praesent orci erat, rhoncus vitae est eu, dictum molestie metus. Cras et fermentum elit. Aenean eget augue lacinia, varius ante in, ullamcorper dolor. Cras viverra purus non egestas consectetur.
            Nulla nec dolor ac lectus convallis aliquet sed a metus. Suspendisse eu imperdiet nunc, id pulvinar risus. Maecenas varius sagittis est, vel fermentum risus accumsan at. Vestibulum sollicitudin dui pharetra sapien volutpat, id convallis mi
            vestibulum. Phasellus commodo sit amet lorem quis imperdiet. Proin nec diam sed urna euismod ultricies at sed urna. Quisque ornare, nulla et vehicula ultrices, massa purus vehicula urna, ac sodales lacus leo vitae mi. Sed congue placerat justo
            at placerat. Aenean suscipit fringilla vehicula. Quisque iaculis orci vitae arcu commodo maximus. Maecenas nec nunc rutrum, cursus elit quis, porttitor sapien. Sed ac hendrerit ipsum, lacinia fringilla velit. Donec ultricies feugiat dictum.
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
          <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This makes a new blank page right after the content. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @media print, you need to add !important in your styles, or the page will use the element's styles that have higher priority.

Since

```
footer, header {
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
}
```

is overriding your header and footer styles in the `@media print`